# Using the Tridion UGC web service to add ratings

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery, ugc

I know I can add comments through the UGC web service by using something like the following:-

```
WebServiceClient ugcCall = new WebServiceClient();

string ugcData = "{ \"d\" :{\"Content\":\"" + comment + "\",\"Status\":2,\"ItemPublicationId\":\"" + PublicationId + "\",\"ItemId\":\"" + itemid + "\",\"ItemType\":\"16\",\"Id\":0,\"ModeratedDate\":\"\",\"LastModifiedDate\":\"\",\"CreationDate\":\"\",\"Score\":0,\"Moderator\":\"\",\"User\":{\"Id\":\"ACME%5Cjbloggs\",\"Name\":\"Joe Bloggs\"}}}";

string result = ugcCall.UploadString("/Comments", "POST", ugcData);
```

My question is what is the syntax for adding ratings and likes and dislikes?  Is this documented anywhere?

MTIA

John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command for uploading ratings is '/Ratings' instead of '/Comments'. The JSON is different too, of course. In the code below, I don't write out the JSON manually, instead I construct a simple Rating object and use the JavascriptSerializer to convert it to JSON:

```
TcmUri tcmUri = new TcmUri(itemUri);
WSR_ContentDelivery.User user = new WSR_ContentDelivery.User { Id = GetUserId() };
WSR_ContentDelivery.Rating rating = new WSR_ContentDelivery.Rating
{
  CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
  LastModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
  ItemPublicationId = tcmUri.PublicationId,
  ItemId = tcmUri.ItemId,
  ItemType = tcmUri.ItemTypeId,
  RatingValue = ratingValue.ToString(),
  User = user,
  Id = "0"
};

JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

WSClient.UploadString("/Ratings", "POST", "{d:" + oSerializer.Serialize(rating) + "}", GetUserId());
```

Comment: Would be nice to add the fact that the WebServiceClient is not public API in UGC and might change in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the example Quirijn!

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Do you have any more info on this?  Are there plans to make it public?  Do you know if any changes are likely in the near future?

Comment: At this moment, there are no plans to make it publicly available but you can rest assured because there are no changes scheduled for that area for the next two releases.